# data:image/svg+xml, none-base64 browser support

Tags: svg, browser-support

that is pretty old theme, but I could not find source of information which could cover it in a simple way, I see couple of hacks and methods how to make it work with IE. 
As far as I see IE9 had issues with that, but since its support is not mandatory for me, I want to still be able to use it and to have capability to 'redraw' my svg icons via CSS. I want to use none encoded svg in my mobile site version.
What about other browsers? I can check in Edge and it seems it is doing just fine with simple `background:url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'` etc. Are there still problems left on mobile browsers with such approach? I mean lack of support.

Comment: You have to at least URLencode some characters such as `#`. From my personal tests, the only fully cross-browser dataURI header is `'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, '` note the `charset=utf8,`, needed by IE10 with some files if I do remember correctly, while IE9 was ok without it. Also, while I still don't have angible proof, I think that the direct dataURI version has more support than the base64 encoded, if that's your question.

Comment: i read couple of articles and it appeared that not base64 encoded SVG was a problem of IE, according to standard second parameter after data:image/svg+xml must be the way it is encoded, but since you use svg+xml that means you use utf8. I got about excluding things which could be used as CSS-selectors. As I understand some browsers can't read css file with rules which include SVG style as well. I trey to add SVG with a class and then manipulate this SVG via this class.

Comment: Well once again it's only from my own tests, but setting this dataURI header does work for IE9 on my VM. Can you provide some links to these articles?

Comment: https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris look here for example. Such articles were popular couple of years ago when SVG became popular

Comment: And that says exactly what i said: you need to URLencode special characters. + I disagree with the no charset, when dealing with img tag, IE10 has issues with the encoding, and their charset declaration is not correct. See my first comment.